# jquery event namespace beginner example

Tags: jquery, namespaces, eventhandler

all,

I am learning jquery event namespace based on http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names 

However, I am still very confused about how to customize a event namespace and how to fire a customise event to selected objects. 

Can someone write me a good example so that I can understand how to use the event namespace better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<p>Has an attached custom event.</p>
<button>Trigger custom event</button>
```

and:

```
$( "p" ).on( "click.myNameSpace", function( event, blah ) {
    alert(blah);
});
$( "button" ).click(function () {
    $( "p" ).trigger( "click.myNameSpace", [ "Wheee!" ] );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I put it into JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/s2jqs8wk/1/          However, I don't understand why there is an alert when I click "p". Can I change click.myNameSpace to myClick?

Comment: As I understand it, the point of namespaces is so you can add and remove handlers without disturbing any other handlers that might be attached to an object.  I would think this would be most useful for the writers of frameworks/libraries/etc as they don't know what else might be happening in the environment they get used in.

Comment: If you call your event myClick it will still be a handler attached to the "p", and it can still be triggered by the code `$( "p" ).trigger(...)`, but since it is not a click handler, clicking on the "p" will not trigger it.  This might or might not be what you want.

Comment: I have updated the example by calling the namespace "myClick". Ad you mentioned before, I can add or remove the handler. Using .on() is adding the handler to the click event, and do you use .off() to remove the handler? Here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/s2jqs8wk/4/